# How can I display double value in TextView with 15 limit precision?

Tags: java, android, double, range

I try this way to display it.

```
DecimalFormat REAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("0.0###############");
double value = 691 / 3600000;
textView1.setText(REAL_FORMATTER.format(value));
```

What's the problem?

1. All the time `TextView` shows:  `0,0`. I thought it should be
   `0,000191944`.
2. This solve may cause problem with number biger than 10. I need
   display double value and I don't know how do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing in Java the default value is int. You can try dividing using this way:

```
 double value = 691 /3600000D
 double value = (double)691/3600000;
```

or when divided with two places precision:

```
 double value = 691.0/36.0
```